# A function that returns a pointer to a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Suppose I have a class called MyClass,

I'm writing a function that should return an object of type Myclass. This object already exists before calling the function. So normally I would do:

```
MyClass function() {
return MyClassInstance;
}
```

But then I remembered about pointers and references and I think doing this will create a new copy of MyClassInstance and return it, which is a waste of memory. So I thought, why not do something like this:

```
MyClass * function() {
return &MyClassInstance;
}
```

So the result could be accessed as,

```
Myclass * object;
object = function();
object->"class member"...
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surely can do like that. It will run ok. It has no problems from the aspect of syntax. But you need take much care that there are more than one pointers pointing to the object. That may bring you some hidden problems.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you provide some details please?

Comment: The code you have written has no problems. But you need to know what you want to do. If you just want to reference the same object somewhere by another pointer, not changing the original object's values, or just change it's values as you suppose. Then that's the perfect way to do it. Because it can save memory by using pointer. If you need a new object, then this way may be harmful. Because there will be two pointers pointing to the only one object. Any changes by using either pointer will affect the object's state. You need to keep care of this situation. Have I expressed myself clearly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are is your final goal here, the syntax looks ok.
But maybe you should read about singleton patterns in c++.